# How to use mole manually in Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio-express, moles

I searched for tags "Moles" and "Visual Studio Express", and found no questions. That probably means I'm the only person trying to use Express with Moles  :)

In Express, there are no options such as "Add moles assembly", or "Add mscorlib".

I've managed to get the tutorial for the DateTime Y2Kbug working after manually adding a couple of references that would normally be handled by VS. So, that means that I can mole any of the pre-moled stuff in System or mscorlib, which will be useful.

My problem is that I cannot seem to mole any of my own classes or methods in the SUT. I don't believe that the compiler sees any of the .moles file that contains the assemblies to mole.

I proved (?) this by attempting to exclude DateTime from the Y2kbug tutorial, using:

```
<MoleGeneration>
    <Types>
        <Remove FullName="DateTime!" />
    </Types>
</MoleGeneration>
```

But the "bug" was asserted as usual :)

Is it possible to generate non-System moles as I need them by using something I saw in this forum: stackoverflow.com/questions/6272217/microsoft-moles-dynamically-instrument

```
Call Microsoft.Moles.Framework.Moles.MoleRuntime.SetMole(Delegate _stub, object _receiver, MethodInfo method);
```

If I use the "SetMole" method, does that mean that I don't need "assembly" files which are not seen anyway? If so, would it be possible to give some examples of the use of "SetMole". (I'm not a techie.)

As suggested by Mike Christian, I used moles.exe OrigValueP.dll. This created OrigValueP.Moles.dll in the MolesAssemblies subfolder.

Add OrigValueP.Moles.dll as a reference to the test project.

View OrigValueP.Moles in the Object Browser. I now see MOrigValue.AllInstances. So that's a huge step forward.

However, I don't see any Moles equivalent of my method:

```
public string TestString() { return "Original value"; }
```

[Deleted lines relating to the command, "moles.exe OrigValueP.Moles.dll", because MC suggested I'm "attempting to mole the mole assembly".]

So, I have one question (which I will continue to try to answer myself): Why was there no Moled method for TestString()?

Answer (score 0):

The Moles documentation states Moles is compatible with Visual Studio 2008 Professional or Visual Studio 2010 Professional or better.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molestutorial.docx

Don't forget that executing the moles compiler via command line requires that you perform compilation in the following order:
  1. Target assemblies
  2. Moles (against the target assemblies)
  3. Test assemblies

The Moles Manual provides the following command line instruction:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/molesmanual.docx

> **Code Generation Command Line** The Moles framework includes a command-line application that can generate the code by following the
>   instructions in .moles files or directly from assemblies. By default,
>   the command-line tool compiles the stub types and mole types into an
>   assembly and places it into a MolesAssemblies subfolder. The following
>   list shows examples of typical usage.
>
> Generate mole types and stub types for a particular
>   assembly  **moles.exe assembly.dll** Generate mole types and stub types
>   from an existing .moles file  **moles.exe assembly.moles** Generate
>   mole types and stub types under a particular namespace    **moles.exe
>   assembly .dll /nf:MyNamespace** Get detailed help about usage of
>   moles.exe     **moles.exe help**

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll make a start on all the suggestions now. Because Express users have found ways to "manually" bypass many restrictions, I wondered whether it was also possible to manually force Moles to work. Remember that it works for "System" and "mscorlib" classes and methods (which is very useful), so I'm just trying to see if I can force it to work with user-written code.

Answer (score 0):

[This whole answer has been appended to the original question. Sorry for all the mess.]

Comment: I suggest appending this content to your original question, as an updated section.

Comment: I assume TestString is a parameter that returns a string type.  The output you posted appears to indicate you are attempting to mole the mole assembly.  Usually, a mole assembly appends ".Moles" to the end of the .DLL file name.  I see these both have ".Moles" in them.  The purpose of creating the ".moles" file in the project, is to tell the compiler to compile the Moles assembly.  These files may be the result of the automatic compilation.